# Why is GROUP BY faster than DISTINCT in SQL?

Tags: sql

This article explains that GROUP BY is faster than DISTINCT
https://sqlperformance.com/2017/01/t-sql-queries/surprises-assumptions-group-by-distinct

Why doesn't the implementation of DISTINCT just use the same underlying logic if it's faster?

Comment: First, Aaron explains pretty well why he prefers it in SQL Server.  Second, this is not necessarily true in other databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry I re-read the article and don't see that. Where is the explanation? What is a case where you would prefer DISTINCT over GROUP BY? I tried multiple queries myself in MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite and all were slower with DISTINCT with the same output. The article concludes with "I'd be interested to know if you think there are any scenarios where DISTINCT is better than GROUP BY" which is my question

Comment: I've tried it now, exactly the same execution plan and instructions used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very key part of this article – easily overlooked – is the reference to **"execution plans."**  As presented by the `EXPLAIN *query*` verb.

Every time you present an SQL query to the database engine, it "compiles it" into an "execution plan," which is what the underlying logic actually "executes" to give you the results that you want.  The formulation of this plan is entirely "case by case," and it can be based on quite a number of things, including table sizes and "statistics" which the engine is constantly accumulating about the data which each table contains.

(The `EXPLAIN` verb will present this plan-information to you, for any query.  The format, content, and purpose of it is *entirely* engine-dependent, but the principle is not.)

Therefore, the "take-away" that I suggest that you take from this article is **not** that `GROUP BY` is [always ...] "faster than `DISTINCT`," but rather, *how* the engine goes about its business *such that* [sometimes] this is the case.  It goes without saying that "every engine is different," but the principles governing all of them, by now, are more-or-less the same.

*Whether or not* "this actually turns out to be true, for you, with your data, in your case," is less important than your understanding of what actually happens behind-the-scenes when you submit *any* SQL query to a database engine.  There's much more to it than meets the eye ...

Comment: I tried running EXPLAIN on the two queries to compare but couldn't really understand the implications of the output. I went through multiple queries my company has in production and tried substituting GROUP BY for DISTINCT in MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite and in every case I got a significant speed up. What's a case where DISTINCT might be better?